# using std::tie for sorting

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, std

I use the `std::tie` for the functor to sort a list of structures. But I didn't understand why it didn't work. So here is my code:

```
#include <tuple>


class Point
{
 public:
    double x(void) const;
    double y(void) const;
    double z(void) const;

    double& x(void);
    double& y(void);
    double& z(void);
};

struct Xitem
{
    int ID;
    Point eP;
};


  class X_Struct_Sorter
  {
  public:
       X_Struct_Sorter(){}
      bool operator()(const Xitem& a, const Xitem& b)
       {
            return std::tie(a.eP.x(),a.eP.y(),a.eP.z(),a.ID)
                     <std::tie(b.eP.x(),b.eP.y(),b.eP.z(),b.ID);
       }

  };

 QList<Xitem> X_Structure;
 ///The function I use to sort X_Structure.  
 void sortX_Structure()
 {
       X_Struct_Sorter s();
       qSort(X_Structure.begin(),X_Structure.end(),s);
 }
```

I use the sorter to sort a list of `Xitem`s and what I got is sorting of just `eP.x()`. `eP.y()` isn't sorted.

**THE PROBLEM: 
  The problem here is the order of list of Xitem after use `std::sort()` or `qSort` wasn't like I expect. What i want here is the lexicographical order (`x()->y()->z()->ID`). So I thinked maybe the problem from the functor with the operator.**

UPDATE DATA: 
Here's the data i got after apply this function. 
The syntax is:

```
    ID  | x() | y() | z()
```

The input is:

```
    0 | -38.8001 | 2.28723 | 0
   -1 | 1.26267 | 3.23 | 0
    1 | -38.1815 | 1.67529e-005 | 0
   -1 | -34.9763 | 0.334298 | 0
    2 | -34.2488 | 0.00119263 | 0
   -1 | 0.141234 | 0.839389 | 0
    3 | -38.1815 | 0.00364942 | 0
    -1 | 0.141234 | 0.839409 | 0
    4 | -38.1815 | 1.67529e-005 | 0
   -1 | -34.9763 | 0.334298 | 0
   5 | -38.1815 | 0.333395 | 0
  -1 | -38.1815 | 0.337506 | 0
  .....(sorry but the data is too long!)
```

The output is:

```
     20 | -38.8001 | 2.36565 | 0
     17 | -38.8001 | 0.333395 | 0
     21 | -38.8001 | 3.18365 | 0
     26 | -38.8001 | 0.3343 | 0
     23 | -38.8001 | 0.3343 | 0
     0 | -38.8001 | 2.28723 | 0
    22 | -38.8001 | 3.18364 | 0
    -1 | -38.8001 | 3.64414 | 0
    12 | -38.1815 | 0.334007 | 0 

You can see here in the first line of data. The `y()` of first Xitem is 2.36565 > 0.333395 of second one. So, I got a trouble here.
```

What i expect:

```
    17 | -38.8001 | 0.333395 | 0
     26 | -38.8001 | 0.3343 | 0
     23 | -38.8001 | 0.3343 | 0
     0 | -38.8001 | 2.28723 | 0
    20 | -38.8001 | 2.36565 | 0
     21 | -38.8001 | 3.18365 | 0
    22 | -38.8001 | 3.18364 | 0
    -1 | -38.8001 | 3.64414 | 0
    12 | -38.1815 | 0.334007 | 0
```

Like you see, the order is bad.

Comment: Not necessarily a solution, but try making the `bool operator()` a `const` member. It makes no sense for it not to be `const`, and some implementations of `std::sort` require that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with `const` and what i got is:
`No instance of overload function “std::tie” matches the argument list`

Comment: Do the `x()`, `y()`, `z()` functions return references?

Comment: @interjay No, it returns `double`.

Comment: The code you have shown compiles fine. Aren't you taking `XItem` by `const` reference, by any chance? I.e `bool operator()(const Xitem& a, const Xitem& b);`?

Comment: Are `Point`'s methods really all `private`?

Comment: Please make up your mind - is it about compilation error, or the sort order? :) On SO we focus on *one* issue in one post. If it's about the sorting order, show the code you're using to sort the data.

Comment: Yeah,The problem here is the order of list of Xitem.

Comment: @user3608963 Sorry, but you seem to type faster than you think. Please calm down, and 1) (let me repeat): *show the code you're using to sort the data* 2) is this really your expected output? It's sorted only using `x()` values, so it doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Actually, i understand slowly with English @@.

Comment: @BartoszKP I update all what you said. Sr for my poor words. Exactly, this function I used just sort `x()` not `y()`. That is what i didn't understand.

Comment: @user3608963 The code works, see the demo on Ideone I've posted in my answer.

Comment: Stop changing the question. If someone gives you a solution to the problem you originally asked about, you should accept it and ask another question for the next problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza OK sorry for that. My bad :) I will notice that. The solution is good for this code.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) requires *lvalues*. `Point`'s `x()`, `y()`, and `z()` functions don't return references, hence they give *rvalues*. A simple fix might be providing reference returning getters (e.g. `double& x()`) for `Point`, or at least:

```
double ax = a.eP.x();
double ay = a.eP.y();
double az = a.eP.z();
double bx = b.eP.x();
double by = b.eP.y();
double bz = b.eP.z();

return std::tie(ax, ay, az, a.ID)
           < std::tie(bx, by, bz, b.ID);
```

You can read more on *lvalues* and *rvalues* [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx) for example.

Another possibility given by [jrok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947836/jrok) in the comments is to use [`std::forward_as_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple). However, given your `Point` implementation after your edit it doesn't seem necessary.

Also, as noted in Qt's [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html#qSort-3) you should just use STL algorithms directly, Qt's functions forward the calls to them anyway:

> Historically, Qt used to provide functions which were direct equivalents of many STL algorithmic functions. Starting with Qt 5.0, you are instead encouraged to use directly the implementations available in the STL; most of the Qt ones have been deprecated (although they are still available to keep the old code compiling).

The code you've provided works correctly for `std::vector` and `std::sort`, see a demo on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/mZG0ky).

Comment: [`std::forward_as_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple).